# ASP.NET MVC _Layout.cs is removing my divs?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

```
        <div class="left-sidebar">
            <ul>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Guild", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })</li>
                @*<li>@Html.ActionLink("A", "A", "Home")</li>*@
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("B", "B", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("C", "C", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("D", "D", "Home")</li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="main-content">
            @RenderBody()
            <hr />
        </div>

        <div class="clear" /> // This goes missing on output?!
```

I have a left-sidebar and an main content, I'm using css to make the two divs float side by side. I need the "Clear" so the footer doesn't hover over the divs.

However, when I run the website the preview my Clear divs are gone in the _Layout.cs BUT if I have them in my @RenderBody they appear as they should.

Comment: not sure if this is the reason but the `div` is not allowed to omit the closing element so the form `<div />` is invalid. Put it as `<div class="clear"></div>` instead and check.

Comment: @PawełŁukasik Yes, It is now showing up! Please post it as the answer and I'll give you the points! :)

Comment: done, happy to help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`div` is not allowed to omit the closing element so the form `<div />` is invalid. Put it as `<div class="clear"></div>` instead and check.

From [documentation about div element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/div):

> Tag omission: None, both the starting and ending tag are mandatory.